# UIToolBar with UIBarButtonItems equally spaced regardless of title length

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, autolayout

So I'm tasked with adding buttons to a UIToolBar and setting the inputAccessoryView of a textView to this UIToolBar.

so I did the basics:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:selector];
UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"longer title2" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:selector];
UIBarButtonItem *item3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title 3 is a lot longer" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:selector];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *divider1 = [self barButtonDivider];
UIBarButtonItem *divider2 = [self barButtonDivider];

UIToolBar *toolBar = [UIToolBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[toolBar setItems:@[spacer,item1,spacer,divider1,spacer,item2,spacer,divider2,spacer,item3,spacer];
self.textView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

So there are more approaches to this.

1) I could subclass a UIToolBar

2) I could subclass a UIView and set a view to be the size I need (width of the superView and height 44), but I'd need to do all of this in Auto-Layout which I tried and could not get right.

Is there a way I can use the above method with a standard ToolBar and get the right spacing where all the buttons no matter how many I use are equal widths?

ETA:, tried the below solution and didn't work:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)spacer {

    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
}

[toolBar setItems:@[[self spacer], item1, [self spacer], divider1, [self spacer], item2, [self spacer], divider2, [self spacer], item3, [self spacer]];
```

Resolved with this solution but I don't like it:

```
 button.width = 150;
```

the buttons would remain equal in portrait or landscape so I guess this is a working solution what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but issue might be in reusing spacer. Try to create new `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` every time you need flexible space.

Comment: tried, didn't work, created a method called -(UIBarButtonItem*)spacer  that returned a new UIBarButton with systemItem type as flexible space then each index I repeated the same flexible space I replaced it with [self spacer], no luck after doing this.